# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable on Report Server Power BI

Tags: reporting-services

I have Power BI Report Server (May 2019) installed on SQL Server 2016 Enterprise working perfectly.

But today I was upgrading to the September 2019 version, the installation completed normally, but when I opened the reports the following message was displayed in the browser:

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

I checked everything:

- I checked logged in log files: C: \ Program Files \ Microsoft Power BI Report Server \ PBIRS \ LogFiles, but found no errors.
- I checked if service stopped.
- I uninstalled and installed, but the same error occurred.

But I was able to install Power BI Report Server (September 2019) on another server running SQL Server 2014.

Has anyone had this problem?
Is it a bug in this release, which does not let install in SQL Server 2016, only in SQL 2014.

Thanks.
_Keny

Comment: Known issue. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Report-Server-September-2019-instance-name-in-URL-suddenly-case/idi-p/804401/page/2#comments   A fix came out yesterday. Check the download page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for the tip